# SQL update from other table when value is NULL

Tags: sql

I have the following problem: there is a table "orders" that contains all customer orders. There are however many values in the column "emloyee_supervisor" (ID of the supevisor of the employee who did the transaction) NULL. The information on that is stored in a table on the emplyoees themselves, "employees", in a column called "supervisor". Now i want to update the NULL (that is take the value from "employees" to "orders"). How can i do that?

The key of an employee is the employee_id (used as key in "employees"), the key of an order is order_id.

I am using DBvisualizer.

I am not allowed to share the real data, but this is what the input conceptually looks like:

[image]

This is the desired output ("employees" table of course not changed)

[image]

Comment: Could you please share sample data, desired output and clarify what RDBMS you use

Comment: What is relation between `Orders` & `Employees`. Also which database you are using sql server, oracle or ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
update o
set o.emloyee_supervisor = e.supervisor 
from orders o
inner join employees e on e.employee_id = o.employee_id
where o.emloyee_supervisor is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below query.

```
update o
set o.emloyee_supervisor = e.supervisor
from orders o
inner join employees e
    on e.employee_id = o.employee_id
where o.emloyee_supervisor is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not tagged with the database you are using.  An answer that should work in any database is:

```
update orders
    set employee_supervisor = 
            (select e.supervisor
             from employees e 
             where e.employee_id = orders.employee_id
            )
where orders.employee_supervisor is null;
```